# gitlab-runner in a custom server

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to setup `gitlab-runner` in a aws instance.

My project is in a group. Hence setting up `group-runner` so that I can use it for other projects in the group.

```
# gitlab-runner version
Version:      11.7.0
Git revision: 8bb608ff
Git branch:   11-7-stable
GO version:   go1.8.7
Built:        2019-01-22T11:46:13+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64


# docker
Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90
docker-machine version 0.16.0, build 702c267f
```

Registered the runner with

```
sudo gitlab-runner register

Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com )
 https://gitlab.com

Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner
 <group runner token>

 Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner
 [hostame] my-runner

Please enter the executor: ssh, docker+machine, docker-ssh+machine, kubernetes, docker, parallels, virtualbox, docker-ssh, shell:
 docker

Please enter the Docker image (eg. ruby:2.1):
 ruby:2.5
```

I can see `my-runner` runner registered from gitlab UI.

Whenever I run/retry the pipeline, it always execute with gitlab's auto-scaling instance.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.7.0-rc1 (6e20bd76)
  on docker-auto-scale ed2dce3a
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.5 ...
Using docker image sha256:feea8cad6f9e7cc58f7ae793ac92bd80fa1ce4da54a381921f161447e978021f for ruby:2.5 ...
Running on runner-ed2dce3a-project-10682917-concurrent-0 via runner-ed2dce3a-srm-1549352595-5d0f29b8...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/dr5nn/gitlab-ci-demo'...
```

Where and what I am missing to run `gitlab-runner` from my custom machine?
Do I need to add `IP address` somewhere or enable some port in my aws instance?

Bellow is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev nodejs
  - ruby -v
  - which ruby
  - gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
  - bundle install --jobs $(nproc)  "${FLAGS[@]}"

rubocop:
  script:
    - bundle exec rubocop
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on right way - all you need is to disable shared gitlab runners for your group or particular project.

Registering group runner enables it for the group, but that doesn't actually disable all other runners - pipeline still chooses the most convenient one based on tags and other criteria.

Other way - use your private tags (not like `docker` and etc) to select runner. Runners pick their jobs according to the set of `tags`, specified for jobs. For example, if job has tags `docker` and `linux`, only runners with such tags can pick it up. So, you can simply mark jobs, which you want to execute on your group runner (and not on shared runners) with tag like `private-runner` and add this tag to your runner.

Comment: I haven't setup specific runners. If I disable shared runner, pipeline shows as stuck (which should be in case of runner has not setup). I can still see runner from UI.

Comment: Do I need to add IP address somewhere or enable some port in my aws instance?

Comment: If you dont want to use gitlab shared runner for specific jobs then just play with tags. Setup tags for these jobs which are only supported by your runners.

Comment: You dont normally have to specify IP addresses in pipeline - workers connect to server by name and server doesnt need to know their IP in advance

Comment: Very new to gitlab-ci. Could you explain how to get this done with (private) tags ?

Comment: Thanks. While registering runner I created a custom tag. And in `.gitlab-ci.yml` specify the tag. It works perfectly.

Comment: Just edited the answer to include short info on tags

Answer (score 0):

With suggestion from grapes. I'm able to run with bellow configurations.

While registering `gitlab-runner` from my aws intance

```
...
...
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
my-tag
...
...
```

And changed `gitlab-ci.yml` file with

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev nodejs
  - ruby -v
  - which ruby
  - gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
  - bundle install --jobs $(nproc)  "${FLAGS[@]}"

rubocop:
  tags:
    - my-tag
  script:
    - bundle exec rubocop
```